# Translating natural language to logical proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are some preconditions:

1. *unary relation constant*: doctor, police
2. *binary relation constant*: like(x,y) means x likes y
3. *object constant*: russel

**How to translate this natural language to the logical proposition:**

i. Every doctor who likes himself also like Russel

ii. There is no police who likes Russel, likes himself

iii. Some police likes all doctors

iv. Every police who likes Russel is a doctor

**Here are my answers:**

ia.$∀x.((doctor(x)\land like(x, x)) \land like(x, russel))$

ib.$∀x.((doctor(x)\land like(x, x)) → like(x, russel))$

***Q1: Which one is the right answer? if not both, what is the right one?***

ii.$∀x.((police(x) \land like(x, russel)) → ¬(like(x,x))$

***Q2: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

iii.$∃x∀y.((police(x) \land doctor(y)) → like(x,y))$

***Q3: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

iv.$∀x.((police(x) \land like(x, russel)) → doctor(x))$

***Q4: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i. Every doctor who likes himself also likes Russel
>
> ia.$∀x.((doctor(x)\land like(x, x)) \land like(x, russel))$
>
> ib.$∀x.((doctor(x)\land like(x, x)) → like(x, russel))$
>
> ***Q1: Which one is the right answer? if not both, what is the right one?***

ib is correct, if you omit the period.

> ii. There is no police who likes Russel, likes himself
>
> ii.$∀x.((police(x) \land like(x, russel)) → ¬(like(x,x))$
>
> ***Q2: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

Yes, if you omit the period.

> iii. Some police likes all doctors
>
> iii.$∃x∀y.((police(x) \land doctor(y)) → like(x,y))$
>
> ***Q3: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

Correction: $∃x∀y\; (\text{police}(x) \land (\text{doctor}(y) →\text{like}(x,y))).$

> iv. Every police who likes Russel is a doctor
>
> iv.$∀x.((police(x) \land like(x, russel)) → doctor(x))$
>
> ***Q4: Is this the right answer? if not, what is the right one?***

Yes, if you omit the period.